# How to parameterize enumerator in rust?

Tags: enums, rust, type-safety

I'm very new to Rust and faced the following simple problem

I have the following 2 enums:

```
enum SourceType{
   File,
   Network
}

enum SourceProperties{
   FileProperties {
       file_path: String
   },
   NetworkProperties {
        ip: String
   }
}
```

Now I'd like to have `HashMap<SourceType, SourceProperties>`, but in such an implementation there is a potential to have mapping `File -> NetworkProperties` which is not what's expected.

I was thinking about to parameterize `enum SourceProperties<T>` with `SourceType` somehow, but it does not seem to be possible. Is there a way to provide such typesafety guarantees?

**UPD:** The intention of having the `enum SourceType` is that the actual `SourceType` is a user input which will be decoded as a `String` value (`"File"`, `"Network"`). So the workflow would look like this

```
"File" -> SourceType::File -> SourceProperties::NetworkProperties
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you actually need the `SourceType` enum?  A common Rust idiom would be only to have `SourceProperties` and determine the type from its variant.

Comment: Since `SourceType` has only two possible values, your hash map can only have zero, one or two elements, and you want to have these two elements to have two fixed types. This doesn't sound like a map to me, but rather like a `struct Sources { file: Option<FileProperties>, network: Option<NetworkProperties> }`. If you want at most (or exactly) one element in the hash map, you can simply use `SourceProperties`, as explained in the previous comment.

Comment: @eggyal The primary intention of having a separate `enum SourceType` was that the application is going to accept user request which would contain the `SourceType` encoded as a `String` value (`"File"`, `"Network"`). So I thought it was sensible to have a separate `enum` for that so the workflow would look as `"File"` -> `SourceType::File` -> `FileProperties`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The reason for having `enum SourceType` is that it is decoded from the user input. So I thought it was natural to define such type. Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use a hash set and an `enum` that encapsulates the properties, for latter matching of them:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct FileProperties {
   file_path: String
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct NetworkProperties {
    ip: String
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
enum Source {
   File(FileProperties),
   Network(NetworkProperties)
}

fn main() {
    let mut set : HashSet<Source> = HashSet::new();
    set.insert(Source::File(FileProperties{file_path: "foo.bar".to_string()}));
    for e in set {
        match e {
            Source::File(properties) => { println!("{}", properties.file_path);}
            Source::Network(properties) => { println!("{}", properties.ip);}
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=844e5381d982a59ebd6ddaeb4366d098)